# Understanding velocity update in Binary Particle Swarm Optimization

Tags: optimization, artificial-intelligence

I am wondering how to interpret the velocity update in a *Binary [Particle Swarm Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization)* (PSO). To recap the velocity update :

```
V(t+1) = V(t) + c1 * r1 * (XlocalBest  - X(t))
                + c2 * r2 * (XglobalBest - X(t))
```

I understand that the binary position vector maps to values in the discrete domain. However, the binary vector contains only `0` and `1`s, where the length of this vector is `n`-dimensional. What I don't get is that the `n` real valued velocity vector takes the `n` binary vector (position), and takes e.g the difference between the local best position at a given index and the current position.

Is it correct that there's only `0`,`1` values that are subtracted for each `X` value in the update ? (So that e.g `c1 * r1` is only multiplied either with `0`, `1` or `-1`)?

How can I use this information in relation to the [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) that is often used in these PSOs? Should I update the velocities, and for example take a particles velocity vector where each element is in the domain `[0,1)`, and put this into the sigmoid function, and turn the corresponding bit positions on or off in the particle's binary vector such as `r < sigmoid(velocity value)`, where `r` is random in `[0,1)`? Does this sound about right, or did I get it wrong?